# IIS. Use HTTPS binding only

Tags: http, iis, binding, https

I have a site on IIS and this site has two bindings: HTTP and  HTTPS. I would like to remove HTTP binding and use HTTPS only. But in that case I must to enter site address llike this **https**://mysite.com. If I enter site address like this mysite.com I have an issue "HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden". Is it possible to configure IIS so I would have only one HTTPS binding and could to enter mysite.com address without setting **https** protocol?

Comment: You could use a URLRewrite rule to push all http://example.com traffic to https://example.com

Comment: Yeah, I know about URLRewrite and tried to use it. But it works only when I have TWO bindings: http and https. Besides I can to configure that at IIS level: SSL settings -> Require SSL. But this require TWO bindings https and https too.

Comment: I asked if it's possible having only ONE binding for https.

Comment: I doubt it.  Is there any reason why you would want to exclude http when you can redirect to https anyway?